# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'regex'

Tags: python, django

Strange error, and I don't understand where is the mistake. The traceback shows nothing relevant:

```
  File "/home/popovvasile/work/intiativa_new/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 27, in check_resolver
    warnings.extend(check_pattern_startswith_slash(pattern))
  File "/home/popovvasile/work/intiativa_new/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 63, in check_pattern_startswith_slash
    regex_pattern = pattern.regex.pattern
```

It seems like something is wrong in the urls.py file:

```
urlpatterns = [
    # Examples:
    url(r'^$', 'newsletter.views.home', name='home'),
    url(r'^contact/$', 'newsletter.views.contact', name='contact'),
    url(r'^about/$', About.as_view(), name='about'),
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),

    url(r'^noway/', include(admin.site.urls)),



    url(r'^petitions/', include('newsletter.petitions_urls', namespace="petitions")),
    url(r'^laws/', include('newsletter.laws_urls', namespace="laws")),


    url(r'^accounts/register/$', RegistrationView.register, {'backend': 'registration.backends.default.DefaultBackend','form_class': UserRegForm}, name='registration_register'),(r'^accounts/', include('registration.urls')),
    url(r'^news/', include('newsletter.news_urls', namespace="news")),
    url(r'^petition-thanks/$', PetitionThanksView.as_view(), name='thanks_petitions'),
    url(r'^addpetitions/$', create_new_petition, name='add_petitions'),
    url(r'^comments/', include('fluent_comments.urls')),

    # url(r'^comments/posted/$', 'newsletter.views.comment_posted' )
]
```

Comment: Would you please provide the *entire* traceback?

Answer (score 3):

There's a trailing tuple lurking somewhere between those lines; the `url(r'^accounts/register/$'...)` line:

```
(r'^accounts/', include('registration.urls'))
```

You intend to have that as a url pattern not a tuple:

```
url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.urls')),
```